Bounding the $L^{p*}$ norm from below for functions satisfying a $p$-capacity estimate
If $1 \le p < n$, the $p$-capacity of a compact set $A \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ with respect to an open set $U$ containing it is defined as $$\text{Cap}_p(A, U) := \inf \left\{\int_U |\nabla u|^p \, dx : u \in C_c^\infty(U), \, u \ge 1 \text{ in } A \right\}.$$
Denote by $C(r, h)$ the cylinder centered at the origin with radius $r$ and height $2h$, i.e. $$C(r, h) := \{(x', x_n) \in \mathbb{R}^n : |x'| < r, |x_n| < h\},$$
where $x' = (x_1, \dots, x_{n - 1})$. Assume $(r_k), (h_k)$ are increasing sequences converging to infinity and set $U_k = C(r_k, h_k)$. I would like to prove the following statement:
Assume $0 < \theta < 1$ and let $A \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be compact. If $u_k \in C^\infty(U_k)$ is such that $u_k \ge 1$ in $A$ and $$\int_{U_k} |\nabla u|^p \, dx \le \theta \cdot \text{Cap}_p(A, U_k), \tag{1} \label{1}$$ then $$ \liminf_{k \to \infty} \frac{1}{|U_k|}\int_{U_k} |u_k|^{p^*} \, dx > 0, \tag{2} \label{2}$$ where $p^* = np/(n - p)$ is the Sobolev conjugate of $p$.
The claim is very easy to prove when $u_k$ is constant in a neighborhood of the boundary $\partial U_k$, say $u_k - a_k \in C_c^\infty(U_k)$. I would like to extend it to the case of nonconstant boundary values.
Here's a proof of the easy case: We will show $a_k > 1 - \theta^{1/p}$. If $a_k \ge 1$, there is nothing to prove. If $a_k < 1$, the function $$v_k = \frac{u_k - a_k}{1 - a_k}$$ is in $C_c^\infty(U_k)$ and $v_k \ge 1$ in $A$. Hence, $$\text{Cap}_p(A, U_k) \le \int_{U_k} |\nabla v_k|^p \, dx \le \frac{\theta}{(1 - a_k)^p} \text{Cap}_p(A, U_k)$$ so that $1 - \theta^{1/p} \le a_k$. Then, by the Sobolev inequality and the assumption \eqref{1} $$\int_{U_k} |u_k - a_k|^{p^*} \, dx \le C \cdot \left(\theta \cdot \text{Cap}_p(A, U_k)\right)^{\frac{p^*}{p}} \implies \limsup_{k \to \infty} \int_{U_k} |u_k - a_k|^{p^*} \, dx \le C, $$ since $\text{Cap}_p(A, U_k) \to \text{Cap}_p(A, \mathbb{R}^n)$. The claim \eqref{2} is now obvious.
In fact, the proof works for any increasing sequence $(U_k)$ with $\bigcup_{k \in \mathbb{N}} U_k = \mathbb{R}^n$. However, extending the claim to functions with nonconstant boundary values will possibly depend on the shape of the domain so that I am happy to work only with cylinders.
